# XSLT:copy-of how to modify content to replace certain elements?

Tags: xslt

I have an input XML document something like this:

```
<text>
    <p>
    Download the software from <link id="blah">
    </p>
</text>
    <links>
    <link id="blah">
    <url>http://blah</url>
    </link>
    </links>
```

And I would like my output document to be:

```
<text>
    <p>
    Download the software from <a href="http://blah"> http://blah </a>
    </p>
</text>
```

That is: I want to copy the existing input document nodes as-is but also replace certain nodes (for instance `<link>`) with an expanded version: based on other information contained in the input document.

I tried to use `<xsl:copy .../>` to first copy in the fragment like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="frag">
<xsl:copy-of select="text"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

But when I then output the variable like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$frag">
```

The output doesn't appear to keep the paragraph tags ? So I'm not sure the xsl-copy has copied the nodes, or just the text somehow ?

If I place in just the following (strip out the `<xsl:variable/>` 'wrapper'), it DOES preserve the tags in the output doc ?

```
<xsl:copy-of select="text"/>
```

But of course, I need to first re-map that 'link' tag to an anchor tag....

I haven't even started to work out how to then replace the contents of the variable (in a new variable of course) with the link information....

Comment: You should have used an xsl:copy-of, or an xsl:apply-templates on $frag, not an xsl:value-of. ;-)

The xsl:value-of effectively takes the string value of $frag, which is more or less like the concatenation of all text nodes that you capture in $frag..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="links"/>
    <xsl:template match="*|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="link">
        <xsl:variable name="link" select="normalize-space(//links/link[@id = current()/@id]/url)"/>
        <a href="{$link}">
            <xsl:value-of select="$link"/>
        </a>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With the following input :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <texts>
        <text>
            <p>
                Download the software from <link id="blah"/>
            </p>
        </text>
        <links>
            <link id="blah">
                <url>http://blah</url>
            </link>
        </links>
    </texts>
```

You get :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<texts>
    <text>
        <p>
            Download the software from <a href="http://blah">http://blah</a>
        </p>
    </text>
</texts>
```

Comment: Good, but why are you using unnecessarily the long form of any XSLT instruction, like: `<xsl:value-of select="$link"></xsl:value-of> `. Not only is this unnecessary, but it results in code that is longer and much more difficult to observe, understand and maintain. Please, in your future answers try to use the short form, such as: `<xsl:value-of select="$link"/>`

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev : I edit my post to take into account your remark.

Comment: @_Vincent Biragnet: Good. What IDE are you usinng?

Comment: OxygenXML, i never really try to change default settings.

Comment: @_Vincent Biragnet: I also have oXygen and use it sometimes. Yes, it generates an end tag, but the moment you enter an `/` before the `>` of the start-tag, oXygen automatically deletes the end-tag. Try it. :)

Comment: Thanks for this - I'll try and incorporate this technique into my actual XSLT ! Cheers

Answer (score 3):

`xsl:copy-of` doesn't do what you want because it creates an exact copy. So don't use it.

`xsl:value-of` doesn't do what you want because it takes the string value and ignores all markup. So don't use it.

You need to use the "modified copy" design pattern, as illustrated in Vincent's answer. This uses two [or more if needed] template rules, a default rule which applies to nodes that are to be copied without change, and a specific rule which is applied to nodes that need to be modified.